# Will Math.random show speed?

Tags: javascript, performance, random

Can I use Javascript to throw the computer a bunch of random mathematical equations, then have it tell me the time taken for the operation?

Will this give a true and accurate representation about the speed of a computer?

I created a sample Javascript code just to document.write numbers up till 50,000.

```js
var start = new Date().getTime();

document.write("<h1>Start</h1><br><h3>Time taken:</h3>");

for (i = 0; i <= 50000; ++i) {  
document.write(i+"\n");
}

var end = new Date().getTime();
var time = end - start;

document.write("<h1>Success.</h1>");



alert("For the program to execute, it took this computer... \n\n" + time + " milliseconds.\n\nOperation was SUCCESSFUL. ✓");
```

Comment: To answer your questions in order: 1) Yes you can! 2) No it won't.

Comment: To Make it short. No.

Comment: Why should math.random give an accurate indication of the speed of your computer?

Comment: `document.write` is _slow_ because it’s a DOM operation. If you modify the DOM in each step it will be much slower than calculating each step and storing it in a string or an array and _then_ writing it. Keep that in mind. If you want to measure speed, I’d suggest using [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) instead.